# Pandas How to ensure unique header/column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas df that was not well-formatted and needed to force the header/column values to be one of the rows of my original `df` (which has duplicate values). The problem is that the header now has duplicates, for e.g:

```
2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 10.0, ..., 10.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, ...
```

I want to ensure the header/columns values have unique values like so:

```
2.0, 2.1, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, ... , 10.8, 10.9, 16.0, 16.1, 16.2, ....
```

and so on.

The new values can exceed `X.9` if needed, it shouldn't matter for my purposes if I get `X.10, X.11, X.12, ....` and so on.

I tried using `df.columns = df.columns.unique()` but then I got an error saying that

> "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 76 elements, new values have 37 elements".

I have looked at other methods as well like `df.duplicates()` and `df.drop_duplicates()` but neither of those seems to be able to provide what it is that I am after.

Thanks!

Comment: why did you need to use one of your dataframe rows to be the header? Could you not have just fed in no header and had the columns automatically indexed?

Comment: try ,  `index_col=None`

Comment: they correspond to IDs so it would be preferable to have that row be the header so I can access by ID. What I meant when I said that the original df was not well-formatted was that the original header corresponded to a single subject which would not have done me any good.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `cumcount`

```
s=samepledf.columns.to_series()
samepledf.columns=s.astype(int).astype(str)+'.'+s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str)

samepledf
Out[199]: 
   2.0   2.1   10.0  10.1
0     1     1     1     1
1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1
3     1     1     1     1
```

---

Data Sample

```
samepledf=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]],columns=[2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 10.0])
samepledf
Out[192]: 
   2.0   2.0   10.0  10.0
0     1     1     1     1
1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1
3     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: I can't quite get an example to work, but would this not break if 2.0 appeared more than 10 times? You'd end up with 3.0 as a column header rather than 2.10?

Comment: @asongtoruin then just `samepledf.columns.to_series().astype(str).reset_index(drop=True)+'.'+samepledf.groupby(level=0,axis=1).cumcount().astype(str)
`

Comment: Nevermind, something got stored weird in memory... Now got "ValueError: Length of passed values is 380, index implies 76
"

Comment: @Wen I think that's worth editing into your answer, at which point I think it'd be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to columns is only for renaming. If you want to just subset the columns and you know you can take either of the duplicately named columns, just do:

```
df = df[df.columns.unique()]
```

Comment: The question is really not related to subsetting though

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
l = [10,10,10,18,18,19,20,21,19,20]
fin=[];d={}
for i in l:
    if d.get(i):
        d[i] = d[i]+0.1
    else:
        d[i] = 0.1
    fin.append(i+d[i])
df.columns = fin
```